# How to access data from form in shopify

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am working on form in shopify where I want to access form data from shopify and send that data into my custom API route . I really tried but didn't find any proper solution . Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue .

Thanks

**code**

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Security Code" style="float: left;border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;width: 200px;"/>
            <button type="submit" style="color: #ffffff;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 700;
display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;transition: all 500ms ease;line-height: 20px;
padding: 15px 20px 10px;background: #ea9215;border: none;border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;"/>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you posted only the html structure. Please, post your js/server api code and beware of CORS.

Comment: @danielarend I am beginner to Shopify , Could you please provide any short example which may written in `.liquid`

Comment: CORS will not allow to do this as a form/action in liquid because it would point to an external server outside your store domain. So liquid is a bad idea. I would think about ajax and JSONP.

Comment: @danielarend Actually, I have requirement . I have one field and one submit button . I want to get value from that field and send it when user click on submit button . Actually, I will that data . I don't know much more about shopify, could you please provide any example or code snippet it would be appreciated